# Redirecting URLs using RegExp and Mod Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect, mod-rewrite

While upgrading Magento to 1.9.3.4 it overwrote the .htaccess file and now I am left with 2000+ broken links that I had manually created.

Since the old product URLs had a random number at the end and now they don't have so I am looking for a way to redirect them.

**Old URLs Structure:**

```
http://example.com/category-1/subcategory/product-name-1421.html
http://example.com/category-2/subcategory/product-name-5421.html
http://example.com/category-3/subcategory/product-name-5891.html
```

**New URLs Structure:**

```
http://example.com/category-1/subcategory/product-name.html
http://example.com/category-2/subcategory/product-name.html
http://example.com/category-3/subcategory/product-name.html
```

I know I can use RegExp something like `RewriteRule ^category/subcategories/(.+?)(-[0-9]+)?$ category/subcategories/$1 [L,R=301]` but I couldn't get it working.

Comment: Why don't you simply fetch the old `.htaccess` file from the backup?

Comment: @arkascha I wish I had a backup copy. The one I have does not have the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: That is very sad to hear. However that happened... I hope my answer below helps, though ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say this probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?category/subcategory/(.+?)-\d+\.html$ /category/subcategory/$1.html [R=301]
```

For this you obviously need the rewriting module activated in your http server. And in case you want to use a dynamic configuration file (see below...) you need to enable that too (see the `AllowOverride` directive).

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).